# track value changement in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I have a variable named Lambda and I want to track how this value change at each iteration. I used dynamic set in GAMS and I defined the following variable:

test1.l(S)=(trackvalue.l(S-1)+trackvalue.l(S))/trackvalue.l(S);

I could not use this in a loop can any one help me to put the result in one variable? or can anyone gives me some hints how to apply this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example trackvalue.l(S-1) is not accessible anymore after you solved the model for S, so you need to store it temporarily. Here is a little example based on the transport example that does something like this. Just have a look at the last few lines:

```
  Sets
       i   canning plants   / seattle, san-diego /
       j   markets          / new-york, chicago, topeka / ;

  Parameters

       a(i)  capacity of plant i in cases
         /    seattle     350
              san-diego   600  /

       b(j)  demand at market j in cases
         /    new-york    325
              chicago     300
              topeka      275  / ;

  Table d(i,j)  distance in thousands of miles
                    new-york       chicago      topeka
      seattle          2.5           1.7          1.8
      san-diego        2.5           1.8          1.4  ;

  Scalar f  freight in dollars per case per thousand miles  /90/ ;

  Parameter c(i,j)  transport cost in thousands of dollars per case ;

            c(i,j) = f * d(i,j) / 1000 ;

  Variables
       x(i,j)  shipment quantities in cases
       z       total transportation costs in thousands of dollars ;

  Positive Variable x ;

  Equations
       cost        define objective function
       supply(i)   observe supply limit at plant i
       demand(j)   satisfy demand at market j ;

  cost ..        z  =e=  sum((i,j), c(i,j)*x(i,j)) ;

  supply(i) ..   sum(j, x(i,j))  =l=  a(i) ;

  demand(j) ..   sum(i, x(i,j))  =g=  b(j) ;

  Model transport /all/ ;

  set       s scenarios /1*3/;
  parameter test(s) change of z compared to previous scenario;
  scalar    lastZ solution for z of previous solve /0/;

  loop(s,
    Solve transport using lp minimizing z ;
    test(s) = (z.l-lastZ )/z.l;
    lastZ = z.l;
*   Change the demand a little for the next scenario to see some change
    b(j) = b(j)*uniform(0.95,1.1);
  )

  Display test ;
```

I hope, that helps!

Lutz

Comment: really thank you for the hints :D :D  I am gonna try it and see it does work with me thank you really :D